# jQuery .animate(); not running? Not even jumping, nothing's happening

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I am trying to create an animation on a list (`ul`) of `li`'s. I want to be able to click any `li.answer` and have them all move one by one to the right and then fade out. Then I want them (while invisible) to return to their original places, go back by 100px, and move to the right while fading in, to make it look like one set is disappearing, then another is appearing. (I have a function changing the content between the two animations, and this program is for mobile so I don't want to have more than one set of `li`'s). My problem is that I'm seeing absolutely no animation in my webpage, but I'm also getting no errors and my `console.log()`s are running normally. Thank you, and sorry if this is obvious!

**JS/jQuery:**

```
$(".answer").click(function() {
    animateOut(this);
    console.log("Animation Sent");
  });

function animateOut(thiz) {
  console.log(thiz,"thiz")
  $siblings = $(thiz).siblings();
  $parent = $(thiz).parent();
  $(thiz).animate({
    left: "+=300px",
    opacity: "0"
  })
}

function returnAnimate(thiz, $siblings, $parent) {
  $(thiz).animate({left: "-=400px"})
  $(thiz).animate({
    left: "+=100px",
    opacity: "1"
  })
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.answer {
  position: relative !important;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 7px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  background-color: #FE1263;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0px -5px 0px #b2013f inset;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<li class="activeQuestion">
      <p class="well well-sm col-sm-4" id="questionArea">How Do You Like Your Coffee?</p>
      <ul class="container-fluid col-sm-12">
          <li class="answer"> Black, Like My Soul</li>
          <li class="answer"> I Don't Drink Coffee</li>
          <li class="answer"> Espresso, Double Shot</li>
          <li class="answer"> Skinny Vanilla Latte</li>
      </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: can you paste html also?

Comment: Can you include rendered `html` at Question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

here is the code
HTML

```
 <li class="activeQuestion">
          <p class="well well-sm col-sm-4" id="questionArea">question</p>
          <ul class="container-fluid col-sm-12">

              <li class="answer"> test</li>
              <li class="answer"> test</li>
              <li class="answer"> test</li>
              <li class="answer"> test</li>

          </ul>
     </li>
```

CSS

```
.answer {
  position: relative !important;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 7px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  background-color: #FE1263;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0px -5px 0px #b2013f inset;
}
```

JS

```
$(".answer").click(function() {
var sib=$(this).siblings().andSelf();
var parent=$(this).parent();
    animateOut(sib);
    console.log("Animation Sent");
    returnAnimate(this,sib,parent);
  });

function animateOut(thiz) {
  console.log(thiz,"thiz")
  $siblings = $(thiz).siblings();
  $parent = $(thiz).parent();
  $(thiz).animate({
    left: "+=300px",
    opacity: "0"
  })
}

function returnAnimate(thiz, $siblings, $parent) {
  $($siblings).animate({left: "-=400px"})
  $($siblings).animate({
    left: "+=100px",
    opacity: "1"
  })
}
```

Comment: In the jsFiddle it seems to be working, but not in my project... must be something else, thanks!

Comment: Nope, still something wrong.... Are you familiar with Handlebars.js? I think it might be something with that, might add a setTimeout() later...

Comment: Hello, could you please add the code to the answer instead instead of only having it in a fiddle?

Comment: Sorry,i am not familiar with Handlebars.js